# Gibbs distribution and MCMC

Tags: distributions, bayesian, sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, exponential-family

In the paper of An Introduction to HMC for Sampling, I once saw the following statement. My question is that does generic MCMC only apply to Gibbs distribution?  I also noticed that many MCMC related articles always mention the Gibbs distribution. What are the characteristics that make Gibbs so unique?

[image]

Comment: If you set $f(x)$ equal to the negative of the log likelihood function of some other distribution, what do you get?

Comment: The name "Gibbs distribution" is misleading: if $f$ is an arbitrary function, $pi$ is an arbitrary density (assuming $\exp\{-f(x)\}$ is integrable).